# SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-2.6

I am using Python 2.6.6 and is a newbie. I am getting

```
  File "./factorizer.py", line 35
    return {n: factorize_naive(n) for n in nums}
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

in the for statement within the return. It is supposed to return a dict with each element having number as key and list of prime factors as value. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionary comprehensions are only available in Python 2.7 and above. You'll need to use another method, preferably using `dict()`:

```
dict((i, factorize_naive(i)) for i in nums)
```

Comment: Specifically, I would use `dict((n, factorize_naive(n)) for n in nums)` for this example.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Yup, just added it :)

Comment: Hey, you beat me to answering the question, I gotta get my two cents in somewhere.